# Local functions benefits with async methods

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-7.0

According to the Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions):

> There are two common use cases for local functions: public iterator methods and public async methods. Both types of methods generate code that reports errors later than programmers might expect.
>   ...
>   The technique can be employed with async methods to **ensure that exceptions** arising from argument validation **are thrown before the asynchronous work begins**:

```
public Task<string> PerformLongRunningWork(string address, int index, string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
        throw new ArgumentException(message: "An address is required", paramName: nameof(address));
    if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(index), message: "The index must be non-negative");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        throw new ArgumentException(message: "You must supply a name", paramName: nameof(name));

    return longRunningWorkImplementation();

    async Task<string> longRunningWorkImplementation()
    {
        var interimResult = await FirstWork(address);
        var secondResult = await SecondStep(index, name);
        return $"The results are {interimResult} and {secondResult}. Enjoy.";
    }
}
```

I don't really understand this example. If we just get rid of the local function and extract its contents to the outer scope and put them right after the validation, won't we achieve the same result? What does the local function actually give in this case?

If it actually doesn't improve anything, can you come up with a better example?

Comment: it gives you an ability to validate the data and throw an exception before running `async` operation, otherwise you can observe an exception only when operation is awaited

Comment: That said, I personally find the benefits of this particular use case dubious. [`ArgmentException` and friends should never be caught](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/), so where they're thrown is immaterial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between:

1. Call `PerformLongRunningWork` and it throws an exception.
2. Call `PerformLongRunningWork` and it successfully executes, and gives you back a `Task<string>` which contains an exception.

That is:

```
Task<string> task;
try
{
    task = PerformLongRunningOperation();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // PerformLongRunningOperation itself threw
}

bool containsException = task.IsFaulted;

try
{
    string result = await task;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // The Task<string> returned from PerformLongRunningWork contained an exception
}
```

If you throw an exception from an `async Task` method, that exception is wrapped up inside the `Task` which is returned.

Therefore, your example with a non-`async` method which delegates to an `async` local function will throw those `ArgumentException` directly when it's called, and not return them wrapped up in the `Task<string>` it returns.

If you rewrote the example to remove the local function and instead make `PerformLongRunningWork` `async`, then those `ArgumentExceptions` would be wrapped up inside the `Task<string>` returned.

Which one you want to do is a matter of debate.

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits: I don't have to pass local variables and parameters as parameters to the other method since they are already captured.

Another use case that I benefit from frequently is working with `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. An example of that:

```
public Task<T> DoSomeWorkAsync()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<T> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    SomeBackgroundWorker worker = new SomeBackgroundWorker();
    worker.OnWorkComplete += workComplete;
    worker.DoSomeWorkInABackgroundThread();
    return completionSource.Task;

    void workComplete(T workResult)
    {
        worker.OnWorkComplete -= workComplete;
        completionSource.SetResult(workResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is not "local function or normal method", but rather "why have a local function at all?"