# Why is better to use a local function instead of just inlining the code?

Tags: c#, local-functions

I've found this code in [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs#L71):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
    return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

At first I didn't understand this part `return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()`, but I realized that it's a local function called and declared in the same line. It was done [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/commit/8fbb540fd140b6d0008120c37abd00e129203cc6).

My question is: is there any advantage over simply inlining that code?

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey>? comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
    var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            yield return element;
    }
}
```

I'd say the current version is more verbose and has more indentation, so what is the advantage? Is just a matter of taste?

Comment: [Very relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-functions-and-exceptions)

Comment: Before local methods this would have been implemented with 2 methods, the first method would call the second method after the null checks.  The introduction of local methods allows all of the implementation to be inside of one method now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would one define a local function in C# just to call it right away (in context of IEnumerable<T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533438/why-would-one-define-a-local-function-in-c-sharp-just-to-call-it-right-away-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local functions benefits with async methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59823222/11683)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The version with the local method will throw *immediately* if `source` or `keySelector` is null, because it's not implemented with an iterator block.

The "inlined" version uses an iterator block, so none of the code - including the validation - will execute until the calling code starts to iterate over the returned `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

In general, eager validation makes it easier to spot and understand errors: the stack trace is clearer, and there's no delay between "making the broken call" and "seeing the failure".

The same approach can also be used to write task-returning methods that fail eagerly: write a "regular" task-returning method that calls an async local method after performing validation.

Comment: "making the broken call" and "seeing the failure" don't need quotation marks around them. (Ironically, they do in this comment)